Isometry group of the orthogonal group
Fix $n \geq 1$, and $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ denote the smooth of $n$ by $n$ matrices with real entries. Let $(X^i_j)$ denote the standard coordinates on $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$. That is, $X^i_j:\mathbb R^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ sends a matrix to its $(i,j)$th entry. Then for each $X \in  \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, we can identify the tangent space $T_X \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ with $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ via
$$E^i_j \longleftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial X^i_j}\bigg|_{X}.$$
Under the identification above, the Euclidean metric $\overline g$ on $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ at $X$ is given by
$$\overline g_X(A,B) = \text{Trace}(AB^T) = \text{Trace}(A^TB)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n A^i_j B^i_j.$$
Now, let $O(n)$ denote the Lie group consisting of all $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ such that $AA^T = A^TA = I$. I know that $O(n)$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$, so $\overline g$ induces a Riemannian metric $g$ on $O(n)$ given by the same formula as $\overline g$ above. This metric $g$ is bi-invariant, meaning that the translations and right translations by elements of $O(n)$ are Riemannian isometries of $(O(n), g)$.
What is the isometry group of  $(O(n), g)$? I know that left and right translations by $A \in O(n)$ are isometries, and  the map $O(n) \rightarrow O(n)$ given by $X \mapsto X^T$ is an isometry. Are there any isometries which aren't a composition of these? Is there a nice description of the isometry group of  $(O(n), g)$?

This is only a partial answer:
You can see from here (and links from there) that the the isometry group, or at least some components of it including the identity component, will be $O(n) \times O(n) / Z(O(n))$. In effect this is covering the left and right translations (modulo the centre as translations by the centre are both left and right).
So the only other pieces needed are  finite order isometries creating additional components (e.g. your $X \mapsto X^T$). Not sure what the possible ones are in general but I imagine $O(4)$ might have an extra one related to swapping the simple components of its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(4) \cong \mathfrak{so}(3) \oplus \mathfrak{so}(3)$ (certainly $\operatorname{Spin}(4)$ should have one).
